# How to populate a Database with emails using a Windows Service?

Tags: c#, database, email, windows-services

I'm Looking for Code to populate a Microsoft Sql Server Database, with my email inbox and i would like it to be done by a Windows service so the users don't know its happening.

How do i get my windows service to populate my Database?

My Database is called Email_Log, 
With Tables:
Email_ID
e_To
e_From
e_Subject
e_Date

My Insert Code will look something like.

```
INSERT INTO Email_Log
(Email_ID, e_To, e_From, e_Subject, e_Date)
VALUES
(Data, data, data, data, data)
```

I have used OpenPop before to create webservice to retrieve mails, so i know how to do that, my exp with windows services are ... none and with databases very little.

I'm looking for some example code on how to do this? or some useful links to sights that have done something similar to this. I have looked online and can't find any help in what i'm trying to do. I just need a push start. Following an example is the best way to start.

Comment: What kind of email inbox are you using? Exchange/Outlook? Or something else? You should split your problem in first reading the emails, writing some data to a database, creating a windows service and then integrating these together.

Comment: Gmail, Yes think i'm going to first get my service to receive the values i want to populate the DB first. So leaving the population of the DB should come last? i don't have to worry about that yet? I'm scared i miss steps.

Comment: Where in the windows service would i put the code to retrieve the email values. Eg would i put it in the event_log?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- For authoring Windows Services in .NET => [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412.aspx).
- For accessing a SQL database in .NET => [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa286484.aspx)

So for example here's how a sample `INSERT` query might look like using plain ADO.NET:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("your connection string to the database"))
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = 
        @"
        INSERT INTO Email_Log
        (Email_ID, e_To, e_From, e_Subject, e_Date)
        VALUES
        (@id, @to, @from, @subject, @date)
        ";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 123);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to", "foo@bar.com");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from", "baz@boo.com");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subject", "some subject");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Now);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Ok great yes that looks good, ok i'm going to try start getting my service to populate ((at)id, (at)to, (at)from, (at)subject, (at)date) with the correct info. Thanks a lot :D

Comment: How would i obtain the connection String?

Comment: You could put it in the [connectionStrings section](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=8067328) of your app.config file and then retrieve it using `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDb"].ConnectionString` where `MyDb` is the key you used to store the connection string under in your config file.